# Ext.Layer with a panel in it

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to figure out how layers in Ext work. The [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Layer) is very concise and I can't find a lot about them anywhere else, other than a [forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?11867-Layer-Example) where Jack Slocum says they're very simple.

I have a working tree panel, and what I'm now trying to do is put that in a layer so it floats over the page (it's meant as a helper dialog that pops up next to a form element). I've only gotten as far as creating a simple layer with a `<div>` element in it, but can't get it to contain more advanced stuff. Looking at the [Combo source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/source/Combo.html#Ext-form-ComboBox), which uses a Layer for the option list, also didn't make me much wiser.

So, can someone with a little more experience on this subject please tell me: how are you really supposed to use Ext.Layer? Or am I "doing it wrong"? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Ext.Layer` is an extension of `Ext.element`, rather than being an extension of `Ext.Component`.

`Ext.Element` doesn't benefit from all the component config options and methods that say an `Ext.Panel` does, and so you're going to have a much harder time adding a tree panel **to an `Ext.Layer`** than if you added the tree panel to an `Ext.Window` which already benefits from shim and shadow (the two main reasons you would want to use an `Ext.Layer`).

But before I would resort to using `Ext.Window` to wrap the tree panel, I would take a look at the shadow config option in tree panel which should provide the 'floating' effect you want...

> true (or a valid Ext.Shadow Ext.Shadow.mode value) to display a shadow behind the panel, false to display no shadow (defaults to 'sides'). Note that this option only applies when floating = true.

Comment: Thanks - the `floating` option in Ext.Panel was what I was looking for. It wraps the panel in a layer. In my case I had to set it to `{ constrain: true }` to make sure it was placed inside the visible part of the iframe.